# Python requests in IIS always times out

Tags: python, iis, flask, python-requests

I have a flask application running on a IIS server. Everything works fine, however I always get a timeout error when using requests.

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://github.com')
```

Using web services is therefore impossible.

I have tried using headers with the requests. But still the same result:

```
headers = {'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36'}
r = requests.get('https://github.com', headers=headers)
```

Also tried increasing the timeouts limits, both in code and in the IIS.

Also tried changing the Identity field under Process Model section to LocalSystem.

I'm not familiar with IIS and I cannot think of anything else. Need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I think this issue is not related with the IIS. It seems your network issue.

I suggest you could firstly check your server's firewall to make sure you let your server could access the internet.

If you need to use proxy to access the internet, I suggest you could try to add below settings in your web.config for your flask application.

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy>
      <proxy
        proxyaddress="The IP address"
        bypassonlocal="true"
      />
    </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

Details, you could see this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/network/defaultproxy-element-network-settings).

Comment: Yeah, I think you right. I can't even ping to an outside IP.

Comment: I suggest you could connect to your server's network administrator to make sure the server could access the internet